# accessing Clojure's thread-first macro arguments

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I was wondering if there was a way to access the arguments value of a thread-first macro in Clojure while it is being executed on.
for example:

```
(def x {:a 1 :b 2})
(-> x
    (assoc :a 20) ;; I want the value of x after this step
    (assoc :b (:a x))) ;; {:a 20, :b 1}
```

It has come to my attention that this works:

```
(-> x 
    (assoc :a 20) 
    ((fn [x] (assoc x :b (:a x))))) ;; {:a 20, :b 20}
```

But are there any other ways to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `as->`:

```
(let [x {:a 1 :b 2}]
    (as-> x it
        (assoc it :a 20)                                             
        (assoc it :b (:a it))))
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [akond's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54196767/10889072), note that using `as->` can get quite confusing quickly. I recommend either extracting a top level function for these cases, or trying to use `as->` in `->` only:

```clj
(-> something
    (process-something)
    (as-> $ (do-something $ (very-complicated $)))
    (finish-processing))
```